# Send html-Mail to new simplenews subscriber

Tags: rules, emails

I have installed simplenews and I want to send follow-up HTML-Mails to newly newsletter subcribers after one, two and three weeks. It only works to send a mail immediately after subscribtion (via rules), but not with the time delay (via rules and rules scheduler)

What I did:
I created a new rule with the event "a user has been subscribed". I added an action with a new component "send follow-up emails" with the identifier "Follow-up email for [mail:value]"
In the component I use [mail:value] as recipient address. As data type I choose "User", but I think, thats wrong. The simplenews subscribers are not registred users. No idea which data type I need.

Any Ideas?